# Error inserting data into orc table

Tags: orc

Even am facing the same problem of loading data from a text format table to orc format table.When i try to load data from a text format table to orc table am getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask"

This is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver;

public class HiveJdbcClient {

private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hdn01.sasken.com:10000/default", "","");
        System.out.println("Connected to Hive");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tempTable = "tempTable";
        String orcTable= "orcTable";
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ tempTable +" (key int, value   string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE");
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + orcTable + "(key int, value string) CLUSTERED BY (key) INTO 2 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true')");
        String filepath = "/home/ee208961/spark-hive/resto.csv";
        stmt.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '" + filepath + "' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE " + tempTable);
        stmt.execute("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE "+ orcTable +" SELECT * FROM "+ tempTable);
        String sql = "select * from " + orcTable;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" +   res.getString(2));
        }
```

am getting error on this line "stmt.execute("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE "+ orcTable +" SELECT * FROM "+ tempTable)"

can any1 please help me in fixing this issue? 
Thanku.

Comment: The Java stack trace is in the YARN logs *(if the job could start)* and/or in the HiveServer2 logs. For the YARN logs, check with your Hadoop admin. For the HiveServer2 logs, check with your Hadoop admin about property `hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled` and develop the client interface based on  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/0.14.0/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveStatement.java#HiveStatement.hasMoreLogs%28%29

Comment: And, of course, you can **debug your actual HQL command** using Hive CLI so that you get all the logs straight in the console.

Comment: Thanku samson for your response.

Comment: Answering my own Question, The actual problem was,that i had not given username and password for the connection and hence it was treating me as "anonymous" and was denying permissions,but when i gave username and password in the statement "Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hdn01.sasken.com:10000/default", "my_username","my_password") " the issue got resolved.